# surefire-junit47 from parent POM prevents JUnit 5 test detection

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, parent-pom

Due to company policy, my project must inherit from a parent POM, which I cannot change. The parent POM defines the following surefire plugin in the `pluginManagement` section:

```xml
<build>
   <pluginManagment>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
              <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </dependencyManagement>
</build>
```

This forces the surefire Provider to JUnit Core (4.7+). However, my project uses JUnit 5.7.0 exclusively. I can run unit tests from the IDE, no problem. But when I run `mvn clean test`, none of the unit tests are detected:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

- To debug, I removed the reference to the parent POM and copied the contents of the parent POM to my project's POM and got the same results. When I deleted the surefire plugin definition above from `pluginManagement`, everything worked as expected. All tests detected and run.
- Back to the original setup with parent POM, in my `pluginManagement` section, I tried overriding `maven-surefire-plugin` without the `surefire-junit47` dependency. I added a `junit-platform-surefire-provider` dependency, but get a `ForkedProcessEvent` error, since both JUnit 4 and 5 providers conflict. It seems like my dependency is just added to the one from parent POM.

How can I exclude or override the parent POM's `maven-surefire-plugin` dependency from the child POM?

- maven version: 3.6.3
- maven compiler version: 3.8.1

Comment: Then you have to change the parent ...cause defining the provider for surefire is by definition wrong. Let surefire/failsafe do it's own work.

Comment: Had a similar issue. Really hard to understand what is going on when there is no feedback from maven.